# Automate image upload with Selenium but without AutoIt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, playwright

I have a non-traditional, image upload button on my company's website. I want to have an automated way to upload an image using this button, but without having to use a tool like AutoIt in order to interact with the file explorer.

Here's a sample of this button's HTML:

```
<button ng-click="onClick()" ng-disabled="readOnly" accepted-types="image/*" on-files-selected="onFilesSelected" allow-multiple="true" readonly="readonly">Add images</button>
```

It's a bit different than the usual `input` element, e.g. `<input type="file">`, and it's using AngularJS. Since it's not an `input` element, I don't think I can use Selenium's `sendKeys()` function to input the image's file location on my machine.

Is there any hack or workaround to uploading the image? I was considering things like overwriting the `onClick()` function to do read from a specified location (this approach doesn't really seem like it's doable), or possibly intercepting the event that opens the file explorer and trying to hack my way from there, but these are all just unsupported and untested approaches to solving the problem.

Would it be possible to do this in another browser-automation tool, like Microsoft's Playwright?

Comment: What does onClick() do? Open the operating system file selector dialog?

Comment: The `onClick()` creates an `input` element with `type="file"`, which is then clicked, which I assume then opens the OS file selector dialog

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39500300/2687446 It sounds to me like this would work to prevent the file dialog from opening, at which point you could use sendKeys to set the value of the `input`

Comment: Just another hard approach would be finding out the API call (if any) responsible for upload and then write a custom js function that takes the filepath and make a post/put call. Check if there is any API associated with the upload, and l can help you out writing this js function.

Comment: With Playwright, you could also explore calling the `onFilesSelected` method directly (and bypassing this UI element). See Playwright docs for `page.evaluate`

Answer (score 0):

Use JACOB it provides java native interface where you can use AutoIt functionalities with selenium here is a sample I am using it in most of the places like MSTeams,Slack for Automation[Upload Feature] it does the job.

## List of Steps you need to do before jumping to the code:

Step 1:
Download JACOB jar

Step 2: 
Register the AutoIt COM libraries e.g regsvr32 AutoItX3_x64.dll

### Use these in your code

- jacob.jar
- AutoItX4Java.jar
- jacob-1.18-x64.dll
- jacob-1.18-x86.dll

#### Sample Code:

[This Code Interacts with file explorer]

```
import com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader;

import autoitx4java.AutoItX;

public class Attachments {

   public void uploadAttachments(){

        File f = new File("Location");
        File[] fil =f.listFiles();

        //Upload Button Xpath
        WebElement uploadFromComp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Upload from my computer')]"));
        uploadFromComp.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        String jacobDllVersionToUse;
        if (jvmBitVersion().contains("32")) {
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.19-x86.dll";
        } else {
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.19-x64.dll";
        }

        File file1 = new File("registerAutoItDll", jacobDllVersionToUse);
        System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file1.getAbsolutePath());

        AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
        x.winWaitActive("Open");
        x.sleep(5000);
        x.send(fil[j].getAbsolutePath());
        x.send("{ENTER}", false);
}}
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is 100% posible with playwright and it is lot simplier then in the Selenium.

```
// Select one file
await page.setInputFiles('input#upload', 'myfile.pdf');

// Select multiple files
await page.setInputFiles('input#upload', ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']);
```

See more on:
https://playwright.dev/docs/input#upload-files